# unpickling AttributeError

Tags: python, pickle

I have just downloaded a pickled dataset from Baidu.com, I tried to unpickle it but I receive this error

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DataSet' on <module '__main__' from 'directory'>
```

would be so grateful if you help me out.

I tried the code below.
I used 'latin1' because I thought the pickle file may have been dumped in python 2 while I am using python 3. But received the same error in the following.

```
with open('name.pkl','rb') as f:
    abc = pickle.load(f ,encoding='latin1')
```

---

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'DataSet' on <module '__main__' from 'directory'>
```

Comment: This likely means there's some module that you need to import

Comment: Is this the whole file you're using to load the pickle?  Is `DataSet` a class you're expecting to load?  Some more context would be helpful.

Comment: yes, the whole file is pickled. Dataset is not a class, but as Calvin said there must be a missing module. but the question is how to import the missing module?